# ResourceReferenceKeyNotFoundException on NotifyIcon

Tags: c#, wpf, notifyicon

I'm using [WPF NotifyIcon](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon), and actually I'm trying to learn how to display a simple NotifyIcon in the system tray. Actually In the `MainWindow` I put this code:

```
 private TaskbarIcon tb;

 public MainWindow()
 {
      InitializeComponent();       
 }

 private void MetroWindow_StateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      if (WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
      {
          tb = (TaskbarIcon)FindResource("TestNotifyIcon");
      }
 }
```

essentially when the main window is minimized the tb should show the Icon declared in a Dictionary like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PrimoCalendarExport.Utils.Resources.UIDictionary"
                xmlns:tb="http://www.hardcodet.net/taskbar">

<tb:TaskbarIcon x:Key="TestNotifyIcon"
              IconSource="/Utils/Images/Test.ico"
              ToolTipText="hello world" />

</ResourceDictionary>
```

this dictionary of resource is located inside a folder, in particular:

```
Project name  
   \Utils
       \Resources
          \Dictionary
             \InlineToolTip.xaml
```

Now the problem's that when I minimize the main window I get this error:

> ResourceReferenceKeyNotFoundException

so seems that the `TestNotifyIcon` can't be located in the project. I don't know what am I doing wrong, I followed all the steps of the tutorial, someone maybe know my mistake? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are looking in the wrong place for the resource. You are looking in the XAML of the `metro window` however you should be looking in the `main window` XAML specify to the program where to look using something like this: (I am not currently on visual studio)

```
 private void MetroWindow_StateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      if (WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
      {
          tb = (TaskbarIcon)this.FindResource("TestNotifyIcon");
      }
 }
```

or

```
 private void MetroWindow_StateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      if (WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
      {
          tb = (TaskbarIcon)MainWindow.FindResource("TestNotifyIcon");
      }
 }
```

Comment: Uhm good hint, if I put the resource in the App.Xaml instead of MainWindow.xaml? How this should change?

Comment: You would still need to point it to app.xaml the same way you pointed it to the MainWindow

Comment: Ok, you point me in the right way, anyway I finally understand the problem, I missed to declare the file resource in the `App.Xaml` dictionary, now working well, many thanks :)